# Join with Where Clause in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, join, null

I've got two tables that I'm trying to join together with an ID, but only select rows from Table A, where a value in Table B is null.

I tried this:

```
var dbXMLSoccerTeams = (from dbXMLSoccerTeam in data.EFXMLSoccerTeam
     where dbXMLSoccerTeam.ID == (from dbMatchTeam in data.EFMatchingTeamIDs
         where dbMatchTeam.SmarketsID == null
         select dbMatchTeam.XMLSoccerID)
     select dbXMLSoccerTeam);
```

But I get an error saying that operator == can not be used to compare int to iQueryable int

Comment: Indeed - because the result of nested `from ... where ... select` isn't a single value, it's a sequence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to me that you should actually use a join:

```
var dbXMLSoccerTeams = from dbXMLSoccerTeam in data.EFXMLSoccerTeam
                       join dbMatchTeam in data.EFMatchingTeamIDs
                         on dbXMLSoccerTeam.ID equals dbMatchTeam.XMLSoccerID
                       where dbMatchTeam.SmarketsID == null
                       select dbXMLSoccerTeam;
```

Comment: Cheers, I suspected a join would be the way forward, kudos :)

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
var dbXMLSoccerTeams = (from dbXMLSoccerTeam in data.EFXMLSoccerTeam
                        from dbMatchTeam in data.EFMatchingTeamIDs
                        where dbMatchTeam.SmarketsID == null
                        && dbXMLSoccerTeam.ID == dbMatchTeam.XMLSoccerID
                        select dbXMLSoccerTeam)
```